# Using PHP in a HTML page

Tags: html, css

How would you add a set of html stored in a different file to the current file you are adding it to.

Here is what I mean

```
<body>
<HTML you have stored in /Php/slider_bar.php>
<rest of page>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you want to have common HTML included on multiple pages? If so, please update your question to be clearer.  Also include tags for any server side languages you are able or want to use - otherwise answer will be guessing or too broad.

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP for this here's an example, but you would have to change the .html to .php

Two files, index.php  and  mainMenu.php the others files orders and contact are only there for demonstration.

(mainMenu.php)

```
<div id="mainMenu">
  <a href="index.php">Home</a>
  <a href="orders.php">Orders</a>
  <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
```

Next the index.php

```
<html>
   <body>
      <?php
          require_once 'mainMenu.php'
      ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

So now the index.php page call this all the time, but simply doing

```
   <?php   
      require_once 'mainMenu.php'
    ?>
```

It will call the main menu page and display the menu in each page you put it in

Comment: so if i had mainMenu.php index.php and index.css would i have to put the css for mainMenue.php in the css file or can i add it in the mainMenue.php with a style tag

Comment: call you .css file  style.css or main.css,   but you can use the require_once for your CSS as well (I've never tried it but going to now). So if you have multiple pages that will use the CSS the <?php  require_once 'style.css' ?> will need to be called in each page that you need it in

Comment: Well so im using the Brackets.io software, and you can only preview it in html. so i have Home.css, Slider.php and index.php <- this is my home page. Is there any way i can view it with out having to upload it and did i name the files right

Comment: Files are named correctly, but what do you mean by "Is there any way i can view it with out having to upload it" ?

Comment: well in the brackets i can only view html files, but if i where to upload them (or something with ftp) then i can view it (i think)

Comment: A bit confused lol? but hopefully this clears it up. Since you've changed your files to PHP you can no longer open them normally in a web browser. You need to install xampp,   once you've installed it click "Start" on apache and mySQL. This will now run as a localserver.   Next you will need to move where your files are saved to the following directory path C:\xampp\htdocs\     onces your files are there. Open a webbrowser and type      localhost/foldersname/index.php     folders name is the folder that all the files are in

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91152/discussion-between-keegan-oreilly-and-carl-b).

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you must be referring to a master page?  Here is info on what a master page is and how to use one.

**Master pages** allow you to create publications which have very sophisticated formatting. The "master page" is an HTML page which defines all the elements that remain **consistent on every page** of the publication. The master page can contain advanced table formatting, graphics, style sheet definitions, and other HTML elements. Master pages are especially useful if you want to make your publication conform to the design for your website.

**Master and Content Pages**

Defining a Master Page is just like defining a normal page. Master Pages can contain markup, controls, or code, or any combination of these elements. However, a Master Page can contain a special type of control, called a ContentPlaceHolder control. A **ContentPlaceHolder** defines a region of the master page rendering that can be substituted with content from a page associated to the master. A ContentPlaceHolder can also contain default content, just in case the derive page does not need to override this content.

**The syntax of a ContentPlaceHolder control is given below:**

```
<%-- ContentPlaceHolder control --%>
<asp:contentplaceholder id="SurfText" runat="server"/>

<%-- ContentPlaceHolder with default content --%>
<asp:contentplaceholder id="SurfText" runat="server">
    <h3>Welcome to my surfing shop!</h3>
</asp:contentplaceholder>
```

**To differentiate a Master Page** from a normal page, a Master Page is saved under the **.master** file extension. A page can derive from a Master Page by defining a MasterPageFile attribute on its Page directive, as demonstrated in what is called a content page below.

```
<%@ Page MasterPageFile="Site.master" %>
```

**A Content Page** can declare Content controls that specifically override content placeholder sections in the Master Page. A Content control is associated to a particular ContentPlaceHolder control through its ContentPlaceHolderID property. A Content Page may only contain markup and controls inside Content controls; it cannot have any top-level content of its own. It can, however, have directives or server-side code.

```
<%@ Page MasterPageFile="Site.master" %>

<asp:content id="Content1" contentplaceholderid="SurfText" runat="server">
    Catch a wave and your ridin on top of the world.
</asp:content>
<asp:content id="Content2" contentplaceholderid="Surfing Pic" runat="server">
    <asp:Image id="image1" imageurl="~/images/surfbaby.jpg" runat="server"/>
</asp:content>
```

Comment: this should be a comment, bro

Comment: Well like so 'super long code' and i want to put that in a different file and have that linked in to the page some how.

Comment: @MrNeo Sorry do not understand. The author has very poorly worded the question and is lucky to get responses at all. Very hard to read and understand.

Comment: Sorry, I comment before you edit your post, bro ^^.

Comment: @MrNeo Oh no problem thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is poorly formed.  So I am not 100% on what you are trying to do.  but I am thinking you are trying to including some html from one file inside of another file?

For example have a header file and a footer file and include them in each content file?

If so, there are many ways to do this. But how you go about it, is different depending on the server setup. The easiest method for this is server side includes.

They look something like:

```
<!--#include virtual="insertthisfile.html" -->
```

You might need to names the file with a .shtml extension.  It really all depends of the web server setup.

There are also other type of includes like date, file modification times etc.

```
<!--#echo var="DATE_LOCAL" -->
```

For Apache servers you can see docs at:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html

Look for Basic SSI Directives.

If that is not enabled on your webserver you might need to use a scripting language such as PHP or you could also do it using Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can start to eliminate such an annoyance by using `.php` files instead of `.html` ones. Place the code of each layout part into its own `.php` file and then use PHP `include` statements to embed each file’s contents onto your page.

For example, you can import banner content from a file called `banner.php` in a `<header>` element like this:

```
<header>
<?php
include 'banner.php';
?>
</header>
```

And then you can place footer content in a `<footer>` element in the same manner.

```
<footer>
<?php
include 'footer.php';
?>
</footer>
```

Note that we could also use `require` instead of `include`, but the only difference is that PHP will stop if it cannot retrieve the file whereas it will leave an error message and continue to run if an `include` fails.

**For more info**:
[php.net article on `include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)
[php.net article on `require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)

Comment: What if he doesn't want to use PHP?